# Mocking third party library (ioredis) in typescript tests

Tags: typescript, mocking, sinon, testdoublejs

I am having a surprisingly hard time being able to mock a third party library in my typescript tests.

I am making a library based upon this [typescript-starter](https://github.com/bitjson/typescript-starter) library. It uses ava for testing.

In my case I am trying to mock the main class of `ioredis` so that my tests does not try to set up real database connections.

I have tried to use [sinon](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon),
 [testdouble.js](https://github.com/testdouble/testdouble.js), and [mockery](https://github.com/mfncooper/mockery).

In sinon I have tried the following

```
let redisStub = sinon.stub(IORedis)
sinon.assert.called(redisStub.Cluster)
```

With testdouble I have tried a whole bunch of things, including;

```
td.replace('ioredis') // #1
td.replace('./homeMadeIoredisWrapperClass') // #2
```

I have tried [mockery](https://github.com/mfncooper/mockery)

```
mockery.enable()
mockery.registerMock('ioredis', {some: 'object'})
```

I have also tried numerous other variation, like always using `require('ioredis')` in the methods

Am I trying to do something impossible here? I though stubbing/mocking a database was a very normal thing to do, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Maybe my design is flawed and I am perhaps trying to mock the wrong things? Some help would be much appreciated!

---

Ps. In the case it matters, I am trying to create a pretty simple ioredis connection wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a couple of misunderstandings / issues with my code which caused this. Perhaps this can enlighten someone else stumbling upon this;

1. I was requiring "everything" (`import { MyLibrary } from "myLibrary"`) before the `td.replace` which made the replace statement happen after the code had required the module. The reason was that the example test were designed a specific way in [typescript-starter](https://github.com/bitjson/typescript-starter) repo. I have now made a [PR to fix the underlying problem](https://github.com/bitjson/typescript-starter/pull/58).
2. I was running the ava tests in parallel, which caused the `td.reset()` to happen before some of my callbacks had fired, effectively preventing the `replace` to work in many cases. The solution in ava, use `test.serial(...` in stead of `test(...`. Yes, the test will run slower, but they will work. You can make a separate file for each test to get true parallel runs in ava.

There are also some useful wiki entries in the testdouble GitHub page; https://github.com/testdouble/contributing-tests/wiki/Don%27t-mock-what-you-don%27t-own
https://github.com/testdouble/contributing-tests/wiki/SAFE-test

Hope someone finds this useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can mock ioredis (version 4.16.2) with just sinon. You have to mock the connect method.

```
import ioredis from "ioredis";

sinon.stub(ioredis.prototype, "connect").returns(Promise.resolve());
sinon.stub(ioredis.prototype, "get").returns(Promise.resolve({ data: "hello" }));
```